# Javascript onclick hide div

Tags: javascript

I want to hide this warning div using javascript inside it.

I'm i getting the javascript right? I want to hide/close the div when i click on the close icon (images/close_icon.gif)

```
<div>
  <strong>Warning:</strong>
  These are new products
  <a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close'>
    <img src="images/close_icon.gif" width="6" height="6" alt="Close" onClick="this.close" />
  </a
</div>
```

Comment: do you use a library like jquery or raw javascript ?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

If you want to close it you can either hide it or remove it from the page. To hide it you would do some javascript like:

```
this.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
```

To remove it you use `removeChild`

```
this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);
```

If you had a library like jQuery included then hiding or removing the div would be slightly easier:

```
$(this).parent().hide();
$(this).parent().remove();
```

One other thing, as your `img` is in an anchor the onclick event on the anchor is going to fire as well. As the `href` is set to # then the page will scroll back to the top of the page. Generally it is good practice that if you want a link to do something other than go to its `href` you should set the onclick event to `return false;`

Comment: +1, but he has the `onclick` on the `img`, not the `a`, so that would be `this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none';` and similarly `this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode);`. Unless you recommend moving it. :-)

Comment: Fair point, I misread the question before it was edited. It'd be better if the event was on the anchor anyway.

Comment: Agreed, that's what I recommended too.

Comment: If you're wondering, you can also show (unhide?) the element again by using `this.parentNode.style.display = 'block';`

Comment: or by `this.parentNode.style.display = ''` which will make the browser use the original value for the display property.

Comment: Don't use jQuery's `#hide` and `#remove` functions.  The performance is terrible - see https://github.com/jquery/jquery.com/issues/88#issuecomment-72400007

Answer (score 26):

Simple & Best way:

```
onclick="parentNode.remove()"
```

**Deletes the complete parent from html**

Answer (score 16):

HTML

```
<div id='hideme'><strong>Warning:</strong>These are new products<a href='#' class='close_notification' title='Click to Close'><img src="images/close_icon.gif" width="6" height="6" alt="Close" onClick="hide('hideme')" /></a
```

Javascript:

```
function hide(obj) {

    var el = document.getElementById(obj);

        el.style.display = 'none';

}
```

Comment: Hi, Chris. Thanks for this. I have a query though, is there any way I can add a "transition effect" to it? By transition, I mean, the 'hideme' div will close in a linear style for 2 seconds, something like that. Thanks again!

Comment: Sure, you could set the element to overflow:hidden using javascript, and then using timeouts or setinterval, you could then decrease the height of the div until it reached 0. However, this effect would be much easier with JQuery .animate()

Answer (score 10):

just add onclick handler for anchor tag

```
onclick="this.parentNode.style.display = 'none'"
```

or change onclick handler for img tag

```
onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = 'none'"
```