# Div cannot be hidden using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Trying to hide a div using javascript when a button is pressed,but no luck

```
<div id="show_password">
    <input type="button" value="ok" onclick="hide_div();">
</div>    

function hide_div()
{
    var div = document.getElementById(show_password);
    div.style.display = "none";
}
```

**Here is the fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/mt42S/

Thanks guys...

Comment: You need to put the show_password string in quotes in order to work. For example, var div = document.getElementById('show_password');

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript onclick hide div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515527/javascript-onclick-hide-div)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementById()` takes a string parameter of the id you wish to find.

You're passing `show_password` without quotes. So it thinks you are passing a JS variable and it won't work.

As the original comment says you need to put quotes round `show_password`, so you want:

```
document.getElementById("show_password");
```