# Hide DIV element with onclick command

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Thanks to anyone who helps me solve this issue.

So the issue is I'm trying to hide an element (by class) with an onclick event using a button. But I am unable to do so.

Here's the code on jsfiddle **http://jsfiddle.net/1tpdgrnj/**

Here's the code for those who wish to help me here:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">Hide on button click!!
<button onclick="close();">Close</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function close() {
document.getElementsByClassName("box").style.display = 'none';}
```

**UPDATE**

Refer to the answer below and to the jsfiddle to see how it's different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript onclick hide div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515527/javascript-onclick-hide-div)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/1tpdgrnj/3/)

Change your javascript as follows

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("box")[0].style.display = 'none';
}
```

First change that should be done is, **rename your function name**, as `close` is a keyword in Javascript.

Second one is that, `document.getElementsByClassName()` returns an array and thus to get the first element you should use the index position `0`.

According to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> The Element.getElementsByClassName() method returns a live
>   HTMLCollection containing all child elements which have all of the
>   given class names. When called on the document object, the complete
>   document is searched, including the root node.

Read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName)

Comment: Thanks so much it worked like a charm. Yup was messed up the whole day. Thanks for the help anyways man.

Comment: Great.. :) Glad that it helped you.. :)

Comment: Yup will do. :D Edit: it says I can select after 4 mins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jquery

```
<div class="box">Hide on button click!!
    <button class="close">Close</button>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $(this).parent().hide(); return false;

    });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ppvzd2L/)

You can also do this easily with jQuery.

```
$("#hide").click(function(){
    $(".box").fadeOut(150);
});
```

Comment: Although the above worked out for me, but thanks for providing an alternative.