# Which web framework or library to use for displaying PNG images and basic shapes on them on a web page with unique url per image?

Tags: html, canvas, png

I would like to create a webpage that displays one image at a time with shapes and annotations shown over it. Each image should have a unique URL address in the address bar.

I have a set of images as PNGs. For each image there is a set of shapes (rectangles, polylines - as pairs of x,y coordinates in pixels) and annotations (location on the image x, y in pixels and a short text as string) to be displayed over it.
When user loads the unique url for an image they should see it with shapes displayed on top of it and annotation markers shown as circles. When user presses a button labeled „next“ the page loads the next PNG with its corresponding shapes and annotations. User can click on an annotation marker and a text balloon should open to show the text for the annotation.

How to approach developing this? I am asking since I don’t have an overview of web app frameworks or the current best practices for databases and graphic formats for online content.

I have experience in programming - Python, datascience, Procedural geometry, Unity for game development (C#), Lua - but not for the web.
I can do a WebGL app using Unity to do what i want and link it to a MySQL database but it feels like shooting a fly with bazooka. Maybe there is an easier, simpler way. Any advice or tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The best tip, I think, is in one of the tags of your question: `canvas`.

[Images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) can be drawn onto it, as well as [shapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D)). To handle your markers you could compare the coordinates of a click on the canvas to the coordinates of your markers (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18053642/6070191) for further info on getting the click coordinates). The annotation balloons could be realised by hiding or showing a simple `<div>` [on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515527/javascript-onclick-hide-div).

As for web app frameworks, depending on how fancy it should be you could do it "by hand" in native html and css, or use something with nice predefined components, like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com).

Depending on where you will be hosting this webpage, you will, or will not have to worry about the backend/server. There are numerous hosting providers available that provide user-friendly admin panels.

Comment: Thanks @buboh, I‘ll give it a try